# leafletjs with KML not showing tiles

Tags: kml, openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm moving my map from Google Maps to leaflet and openstreetmap. I'm using the same KML data to show places on the map, but for some reason, the tiles does not show up. I see the places from the KML files but not the map.

Once in a while, the map shows up. However, it mostly doesn't.

Can someone look at my code and tell me what's wrong? http://netkoder.dk/test/test0259.html

**UPDATE**

It appears that when I use `{center: new L.LatLng(X, X), zoom: X}` with certain numbers, it doesn't work well when later using `track.on("loaded", function(e) { map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds()); });` to center the map according to the KML data points.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior you described but I cannot find the error. Did you already try different versions of Leaflet or the layer plugin? Maybe there is some incompatibility between the versions you are using. Does the [kml example](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/kml.html) work for you?

Comment: Maybe the plug in not maintained anymore. It says **update examples to Leaflet 0.7** on github on the examples. But i cant get 0.7 on leaflet website. And the plugin website it not working right now.

Comment: Basically i just want to swith from google maps til something else like openstreetmap. For google maps i used a KML file but maybe it would just be better to convert the KML file to something else so i can avoid needing to use a plugin for leafjet ?